# Question about complex integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I have two questions about integrals.

1.) $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{dw}{\sin{\frac{1}{w}}}$$ where $\gamma$ is the circle $|w| = \frac{1}{5}$.

2.) $$\int_{\gamma_{a}} \frac{z^{2} + e^{z}}{z^{2}(z-2)}dz$$

where $\gamma_{a}$ is the positively oriented circle $|z| = a, a >0, a \neq2.$

For problem $1$, I concluded that the answer is $\frac{1}{6}$ and I got this answer by computing the residue.

$$\frac{1}{\sin{\frac{1}{w}}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{w}} + \frac{\frac{1}{w}}{6} + \frac{7 (\frac{1}{w})^{3}}{360}+...$$

$$ \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{1}{w}}} = w + \frac{1}{6w} + \frac{7}{360w^{3}} +... $$.

But, for the second problem I'm a bit confused about how to go about solving it. If I assume that $a < 2$ then I can do this:

$$ \frac{z^{2} + e^{z}}{z^{2}(z-2)} = \frac{z^{2} +1+z+\frac{z^{2}}{2!}+\frac{z^{3}}{3!}+...}{z^{2}(z-2)}$$

$$ \frac{z^{2} + e^{z}}{z^{2}(z-2)} = \frac{3}{2(z-2)}+\frac{1}{z^{2}(z-2)}+ \frac{1}{z(z-2)} + \frac{z}{6(z-2)} + ...$$

hence, the residue is $\frac{3}{2}$. I'm not sure if this is correct so I would appreicate someone looking over this calculation. Also, I don't know what to do when $a > 2$.

EDIT: From the suggestion in the comments, I did partial fractions on some of the terms in problem 2.

$$ \frac{1}{z^{2}(z-2)} = -\frac{1}{4z} -\frac{1}{2z^{2}} + \frac{1}{4(z-2)} $$

$$ \frac{1}{z(z-2)} = -\frac{1}{2z} =\frac{1}{2(z-2)} $$

So, the residue contributions are ($\frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} -\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}.$) Is this correct? Hence, the answer would be the same as it was when $a < 2 .$

Comment: I would split up the two terms in the denominator using partial fractions. Then apply Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: @zugzug, I cannot do partial fractions over the whole thing as it is not a rational function(due to the exponential). Do you mean partial fractions over the individual terms like $\frac{1}{z^{2}(z-2)}$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I meant partial fractions in order to write it as $\frac{f(z)}{z}+\frac{g(z)}{z^2}+\frac{h(z)}{(z-2)}$.

Comment: You've found the first terms in the Laurent expansion of $f(z) = \csc(1/z)$ around infinity (on $|z| > R$; $f(z)$ doesn't have a Laurent series expansion on $0 < |z| < r$). That gives the residue of $f(z)$ at infinity, which is $-[z^{-1}] f(z) = -1/6$. Then the integral can be evaluated as minus the sum of the residues at $\pm 1/\pi$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem, we enforce the transformation $z\mapsto \frac1w$ to obtain

$$\oint_{|z|=1/5}\frac1{\sin(1/w)}\,dw=\oint_{|z|=5}\frac1{\sin(z)}\frac1{z^2}\,dz\tag1$$

There are 3 poles of $\frac{1}{z^2\sin(z)}$ that are inside the circle $|z|=5$.   These include a third order pole at $z=0$ and simple poles at $z=\pm \pi$.

The associated residues are $1/6$, $-1/\pi^2$, and $-1/\pi^2$.  Putting it all together, we find that

$$\frac1{2\pi i }\oint_{|z|=1/5}\frac1{\sin(1/w)}\,dw=\frac16-\frac2{\pi^2}$$

__

Alternatively, we can evaluate the integral on the left-hand side of $(1)$ directly.  The poles of $\frac1{\sin(1/w)}$ are located at $w=1/(n\pi)$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  All of these poles for $n>1$ are contained inside the circle $|w|=1/5$.

The residue of the pole at $w=1/(n\pi)$ is $(-1)^{n-1}/(n^2\pi^2)^2$.  Hence, we see that

$$\oint_{|z|=1/5}\frac1{\sin(1/w)}\,dw=2\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2\pi^2}=\frac16-\frac2{\pi^2}$$

which agrees with the previous result.

---

---

For the second problem, there is a second order pole at $z=0$ and a simple pole at $z=2$.

The residue at $z=0$ is

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z^2+e^z}{(z-2)}=-3/4$$

The reside at $z=2$ is $\frac{4+e^2}{4}$.

And you can finish.

Comment: It appears that I missed some contributions from other poles. But, could you explain conceptually where my reasoning went wrong? Why can't we use the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{sin(\frac{1}{w})}$? Also, do you have suggestions for problem 2? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Note that the expansion $\sin(1/w)=\frac1w-\frac1{6w^3}+O\left(\frac1{w^5}\right)$ is valid for $|w|>0$.  Do you see the issue?

Comment: I see it now. Thank you.

Comment: You're quite welcome. It was my pleasure.

Comment: As a comment, if we want to evaluate the integral as an infinite sum of the residues at $1/(\pi n)$, we need to show that the residue theorem applies to a region containing the non-isolated singularity at $w = 0$. Or show that we can choose a sequence of smaller and smaller circles around the origin s.t. the sequence of the integrals over the circles tends to zero.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, indeed.  And of course we can choose smaller and smaller excluding disks.